# Build react-router url from input

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How do I add the value from the input field to the url string? In the example below `this.refs.foo` is `undefined`.

```
export class searchTest Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref="foo"/>
        <Link to={`/stuff/${this.refs.foo.value}`}>
          Find recipes!
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.refs.foo` does not exist on the first render, it is created after the first render. You need a safe default, perhaps by pulling out value into a variable before the return statement:

```
export class searchTest Component {
  render() {
    var value = this.refs.foo ? this.refs.foo.value : ''
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref="foo"/>
        <Link to={`/stuff/${value}`}>
          Find recipes!
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But even this won't work unless you have an `onChange` handler attached to the input. As you have it right now, `searchTest` will not re-render on an input change, so the prop passed to `Link` will not update. What you probably want is to keep foo's value in the state of `searchTest`, and have your `Link` be

```
<Link to={`/stuff/${this.state.foo}`}/>
```

instead of using refs.